# why is my t-shirt doesn't sharpen?

Tags: edit-mode

[image]

Hi, I used subsurface modifier, and as you can see the end of the shirt, everything is sharp except for the front ones. I just tried everything to make them sharp instead of being curved. I don't know what is wrong..

Comment: make you can use Un-Subdivide so you can make its poly count smaller.

Answer (score 1):

[duplicate] You have bad normals all over the place, that's what those odd dark shadings are.  Select all verts in edit mode, control n to recalculate normals.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that there are some verticies between the body and the shirt.
Therfore the "front ones" are not the last ones, so it bends inside.